# byte array to int java working in windows not in linux

Tags: java, arrays, windows, ubuntu, integer

I have to read from a byte array and convert into int in java. In windows it works perfectly, I can see the logical sequence number (they are numbers in logical order: 1, 2, 3...). However, in Linux it is not the case, the coversion gives even negative numbers where they are all positive. Could the OS interfering somehow in the conversion?

I let the conversion code that I use for reading from byte array to getting an int:

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) 
{
    return   (int)((b[3] & 0xFF) | (b[2] & 0xFF) << 8 | (b[1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (b[0] & 0xFF) << 24);
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same Java Version ob both operating systems?

Comment: "Could the OS interfering somehow in the conversion?" No. You should check whether the input `b` is the same in both cases.

Comment: I agree with Andy: this code should work exactly the same in all Java platforms. If it produces different output, then the input must be different.

Answer (score 3):

it seems that your code expects the byte array to represent a 32bit integer in big-endian byte order.
I assume that for some reason if you run your code under linux, the byte order is little-endian.
We would need to know where the byte array comes from to guess a reason for this.